# The Lebesgue integral $\int_\Omega dP$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am a beginner.

Given probability measure $P$ and sample space $\Omega$, is it true that:

$$\displaystyle \ \ \int_\Omega dP = 1$$

Comment: Looking at your questions so far, I am beginning to find difficult to figure out what are the things you know and those you do not know... For example, the gap betwwen this present question and [some others of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/243583) is quite daunting.

Comment: @did I'm taking a stochastics course with no background in measure theory so I have holes everywhere, unfortunately!

Comment: [Bad idea](http://areallybadidea.com/).

Comment: I like this one because I was planning to write it on some stickers, and make some jokes about the Wau number :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes as
$$
\int_\Omega \mathrm dP=P(\Omega)=1.
$$

More generally
$$
\int_A\mathrm dP=\int_\Omega 1_A\,\mathrm dP=P(A),\quad A\in\mathcal{F}.
$$